# Pythonic Way of Adding Symbol to String N Times

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string

I'm coding a script that takes a `n` and a list and has to output a string that contains the initial items of the list **plus** some symbol repeated `n` times at the end.

This is the current script:

```
array = ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"]
n = 3
symbol = "$"
for _ in range(n):
    array.append(symbol)
string = " ".join(array) + " "
string.strip(" ")
```

Output:

```
'a a a a a a $ $ $'
```

This script actually work as I need it to, but I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this with some built-in functions for string formation, or something more pythonic than this.

Comment: Instead of the loop you could write `[symbol]*n` to create a list of length `n` with each entry being `symbol`.

Comment: `' '.join(array + [symbol] * n)`

Answer (score 0):

Created a variable `s` and added letters from array to it.
`*` is a repetition operator, So using `*` we can repeat symbol n times.

```
array = ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"]
n = 3
symbol = "$"
s=''
for a in array:
    s += a
print(s + symbol*n)
```